# Wordpress page not found after deactivating Multisite Language Switcher plugin

Tags: wordpress

Hello I am using Wordpress 3.9.2 on localhost.I added a theme,plugins and pages.All was working fine.

Then I installed and activated Multsite Language Switcher plugin.And added English to the languages.But the site currently doesnt support Multisite.

I then decided to remove the plugin and deactivated the plugin and removed English from Settings->Languages.

Now when I try to enter a page other than homepage it says "It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching can help."

The pages and everything is there as before(published and public) but the pages dont open.What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the permalink settings? Ist it still there if you use the "standard" settings?

Comment: Solved..It was because of Polylang plugin.Deactivated polylang and its working now